# Не читает стили css и sass

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

создал локальный сервер через gulp, но не применяются стили,
Помогите пожалуйста
Выводит в консоль такую ошибку:
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/sass/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');

gulp.task('minify-html', () => {
  return gulp
    .src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});

gulp.task('minify-css', async () => {
  return gulp
    .src('app/css/*.css')
    .pipe(
      autoprefixer({
        ovverideBrawserlist: ['last 20 verrsions'],
        cascade: false,
      })
    )
    .pipe(cleanCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'));
});

gulp.task('sassToCss', async () => {
  return gulp
    .src('app/sass/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(
      autoprefixer({
        ovverideBrawserlist: ['last 20 verrsions'],
        cascade: false,
      })
    )
    .pipe(cleanCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/sass/'));
});

gulp.task('minify-js', async () => {
  return gulp.src('*.js').pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'));
});

gulp.task('server', async () => {
  browserSync.init({ server: 'app' });
  browserSync.watch('public/**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('watch-files', async () => {
  gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', gulp.series('minify-css'));
  gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', gulp.series('minify-js'));
  gulp.watch('app/sass/*.sass', gulp.series('sassToCss'));
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', gulp.series('minify-html'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch-files', 'server'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас расширение файла "txt", а не "css".

1. Откройте Проводник или ярлык на рабочем столе "Этот компьютер".
2. Выберите вкладку "Вид" и поставьте галочку напротив пункта "Расширения имен файлов".
3. Уберите .txt в конце названия файла